# Is there a way to read html title from a string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, .net, user-interface

I have some javascript variable in which it has html script something like below:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;" class="ms-fontColor"><i title="Sample Text"></i></div>
```

I want to read just the text that is inside the title tag using javascript or JQuery and get rid of everything else. Is there any way that I can achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean *Something Like* the below?  Is the title attribute always in an I element?  Will the I element always be in a Div Element?

Answer (score 2):

```
const el = document.createElement( 'div' );
el.innerHTML = `<div style="display: inline-block;" class="ms-fontColor"><i title="Sample Text"></i></div>`;

// If there are more than one <i> elements with title attribute you might wanna do this 

const innerEls = el.querySelectorAll('i[title]')

innerEls.forEach(el => {
  const value = el.getAttribute('title') // or el.title
})

// If you just want to get the only or the first <i> with title attribute
const innerEl = el.querySelector('i[title]')
//Here's the attribute value
const value = innerEl.getAttribute('title') // or innerEl.title
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex can help with this.

```js
const str = '<div style="display: inline-block;" class="ms-fontColor"><i title="Sample \"Text"></i></div>';
const reg = /title=('|")(.*)\1/;

console.log(str.match(reg)[2]);
```

Comment: Don&#39;t use a regular expression to parse HTML. It might work now, and you can build a compliant parser from many small, regex tokens, but if they ever used the parser on anything more complicated, it will fail. Specifically, this won&#39;t work on strings with escaped internal quotes. The answer to parsing any non-trivial grammar is generally not with a regular expression. A compliant regex here is like 30+ characters.

Comment: For example, [here's](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax/#string-token-diagram) the railroad diagram to parse a valid CSS string, which is then used to generate a regular expression (or custom logic to parse this). HTML strings are very similar to my knowledge, so simply, this answer won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a second to realize you meant get the title from an HTML String instead of from actual DOM elements. This  will convert the string to an html element for jquery:

```
var $elem = $(document.createElement(htmlString));

var title = $elem.is("[title]") 
    ? $elem.prop("[title]") 
    : $elem.find("[title]").prop("title");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

```js
let str = '<div style="display: inline-block;" class="ms-fontColor"><i title="Sample Text"></i></div>';
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");
console.log(doc.querySelector('i[title]').title);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods you can employ to achieve this some of which depend on the structure of your HTML string. The second approach below works for irrespective of what the structure of your HTML string is.

```js
const str = '<div style="display: inline-block;" class="ms-fontColor"><i title="Sample Text"></i></div><div style="display: inline-block;" class="ms-fontColor"><i title="Sample Text 2"></i></div><div style="display: inline-block;" class="ms-fontColor"><i title="Sample Text 3"></i></div>';

const titles = $(str).find('i[title]').map((index, elem) => elem.title).get();
console.log( titles );

//When the i element is at the top of the hierarchy
const str1 = '<i title="Sample Text"></i><i title="Sample Text 2"></i><i title="Sample Text 3"></i><i title="Sample Text 4"></i><div title="This other sample too">watch this</div>'

//approach 1
const t1 = $(str1).filter('i[title]').map((index, elem) => elem.title).get();
console.log( t1 );
//this approach would not work for `str`

//approach 2
const t21 = $('<div/>').append(str1).find('i[title]').map((index, elem) => elem.title).get();
console.log( t21 );

//this would work for `str` as well
const t22 = $('<div/>').append(str).find('i[title]').map((index, elem) => elem.title).get();
console.log( t22 );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the element using `querySeletor` and on that object just fetch the `title` using `iElement.title`

```js
const iElement = document.querySelector("i");
const title = iElement.title; 
console.log( title );
```

```html
<div style="display: inline-block;" class="ms-fontColor">
  <i title="Sample Text"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: He specified `from string`

Comment: @Areg Ok got it but why downvote. I might have misunderstood a part of the question.